# Need Evernote to check my consumer_key and consumer_secret

Tags: evernote

Below is a note from one of my developers asking me to check my Evernote consumer_key and consumer_secret.  We've had some installation problems with our app and we are wondering if there is anyone at stackoverflow that has any thoughts on this.  Or perhaps someone at stackoverflow works at Evernote and can look into this for me?  Evernote has pretty much shutdown API support and I've had no luck going through Evernote support.

> One thing I have been thinking about tonight is our evernote key.  I
>   think we have talked about this before, and it seems like you weren't
>   the one that created they key.  The standard practice is to create a
>   key in the sandbox environment and then at some point upgrade it to
>   the production environment.  I am wondering if evernote could check
>   our key and make sure everything is right with it.  Here is the
>   relevant lines from our code that has both our key and our "secret"

Comment: Are you able to use your API key and secret at all? On sandbox? On production?

Comment: Based on your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38151674/how-do-i-get-replacement-consumer-key-and-secret), I think this one can be closed.