# How do I get replacement consumer_key and secret?

Tags: evernote

The security on my consumer_key and secret has been compromised and I need replacement keys. Three days ago I filled out the form for a consumer_key and secret.  It did it the same way I did it when I set up my sandbox account and then later moved to my production account.

Evernote says they send out consumer_key within two days of request, but I haven't received anything in three days.  Am I going about this the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Should be taken care of now, sorry about the delay.

For others, FYI: we do indeed keep an eye on questions tagged evernote on Stackoverflow.